# Centered but aligned numbers in tables

Tags: tables

In Latex tables, one has a center, left, or right aligned columns. Is it possible to have the number are centered and aligned so that they appear good when centered? Instead of this;

```
|    1234    |
|   17234    |
|  1238675   |
```

can we have this?

```
|     1234   |
|    17234   |
|  1238675   |
```

Comment: Ì'd suggest loading `siunitx` and using the `S`column type.

Comment: siunitx or dcolumn if you just want this and not the rest of siunitx features

Comment: I see, I'll look at these, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the numbers given in your example, the basic `r` column type, the `S` column type provided by the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, and the `D` column type provided by the [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package actually all produce the exact same output:

[image]

In fact, if you look *really really* closely at the screenshot, you will notice that the third column (which employs the `D` column type) has ever so slightly more whitespace on the right-hand side than do the other two columns. I assume it's because the all-knowing creator [hello, David!] of the `dcolumn` package assumed that the `D` column type would never be used for trivial cases, i.e., for columns in which all numbers are pure integers, i.e., do not possess decimal markers, decimal components, or thousands grouping marks. For such trivial cases, there's no compelling reason for using anything but the `r` column type.

In general, if you have a non-trivial case, i.e., if at least *some* numbers possess decimal markers and decimal componenents (in addition to integer components), either the `S` or the `D` column type is the way to go.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| r | S[table-format=7.0,group-digits=false] | D{.}{.}{7.0} |}
1234 & 1234 & 1234  \\
17234 & 17234 & 17234 \\
1238675 & 1238675 & 1238675 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend this answer for the decimal markers and floats if you have some time?

Comment: @kelalaka - Please provide a few examples of actual numbers you'd like to see typeset.

Comment: like 20,000,212 as decimals. D works for this if you change 7.0 to a larger value. If I try  1,238,675.03 it is messed to right. Never worked for S.

Comment: @kelalaka - Not sure what you mean by "messed to right". For sure, to typeset the number `1238675.03` with `.` ("period", aka "full stop") denoting the decimal marker, you should use either `D{.}{.}{7.2}` ("7 integer digits and 2 decimal digits") or `S[table-format=7.2]`.

Comment: Oh, that is now perfect for `D`. In `S` _12,386.75_ produce an error as a duplicate decimal marker with `S[table-format=7.2`

Comment: @kelalaka -- By default, `siunitx` interprets both `,` and `.` as decimal markers *on input*. That is why `12,386.75` appears to `siunitx` to have two decimal markers, triggering an error message. Either delete the commas that act as thousands separators but are misinterpreted as decimal markers, or specify `S[table-format=7.2, input-ignore={,}, group-separator={,}]`, so that commas ignored *on input* but are used as thousands separators *on output*.

Comment: Thanks, the input ignore doesn't work as intended, however, when the commas are removed from the numbers, the group separator adds as intended.

Comment: @kelalaka - Does the test document `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{siunitx} \begin{document} \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=7.2, input-ignore={,}, group-separator={,}]} 1,234,567.89 \end{tabular} \end{document}` output `1,234,567.89` for you?

Comment: I've got this error `! Package siunitx Error: Duplicate decimal marker token ',' in input.` Maybe I've an old version like `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`

Comment: Oh, you're using a three year old TeX distribution and siunitx package. I'm afraid I have no idea how the syntax works with old version of siunitx. The syntax I was suggesting apparently works only with the current version of siunitx. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I've updated the system ( with some troubles) now, and everything works as intended. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example how to use `spalign` package to have an answer to your question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spaligndelims\vert\vert\spalignvector[c]{1234 17234 1238675} \textup{or} \spalignvector[r]{1234 17234 1238675}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we have table headers, hlines, and vlines easily as in tables?

Comment: Spalign use the matrices. Hence if the code is complicated spalign not is indicated.